GCP API Gateway is caching response when Cache-Control header is set
All infra is on GCP. When I set a "Cache-Control: public, max-age=86400" response header on my endpoint that is served by a 2nd generation cloud function, the API gateway is caching the response. When I change my endpoint to set the "Cache-Control: no-cache" response header, the API gateway continues to return the original response, despite the change in cache header. When I call the function's own endpoint I get the correct cache header value.
The flow is: Load Balancer -> API Gateway -> Cloud Functions.
Calling via LB gives wrong TTL
Calling via API Gateway gives wrong TTL
Calling Cloud Function directly gives correct TTL
The API Gateway docs don't mention caching anywhere, Load Balancer does not have caching/CDNs enabled, and given that API gateway is downstream and calling it produces wrong TTL, seems this is the issue originating from API Gateway.
Steps to reproduce:

Create an API gateway with an endpoint with a 2nd generation cloud function as the backend
The endpoint served by the cloud function should set the "Cache-Control: public, max-age=86400"
Deploy the endpoint and verify the response contains the "Cache-Control: public, max-age=86400" header
Deploy a change to the endpoint, changing the response body, and replacing the "Cache-Control: public, max-age=86400" header with "Cache-Control: no-cache".
Observe that the response from the cloud function's direct URL has changed to contain the "Cache-Control: no-cache" header, but the response from the api gateway URL continues to be the old response with the "Cache-Control: public, max-age=86400" header.

The only way I could clear the cache was to deploy a new gateway with the same api spec. Maybe there is a purge functionality that could be invoked, would be keen to explore the options.

Curious if it is just takes time (For GCP to propagate the cache setting across all those layers) .  Have you tried to change it into another value such as max-age=60 just to see if that gets propagated faster?
Have you also tried Cache-Control: no-store  instead?

Yes, tried changing max=age to different value and had no effect. Have not tried no-store.

I'm not certain if I follow you. You made a HTTP(S) resource cacheable (proxies can serve that resource for the next 24h without checking with the backend) and then you're surprised that a caching proxy does exactly that? The new max-age applies only to new content.
